# Centralizer in O(2,R)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We have an ortogonal group of degree 2 over R.
What is the order and structure of centralizer of subset which is any reflection from O(2,R)?
As far as I know ortogonal group over a finite group is a group for each element in is true what $AA^t=E$

Comment: Try writing down a matrix in $O(2,\mathbb R)$ which is a reflection.

Comment: It shall look like $E-2ww^t$ where w is a vector column of degree 2 so the matrix shall look like  $\begin{array}{cc} 1-2x^2 & -2xy \\ -2xy & 1-2y^2  \end{array}$

Comment: Since all the reflections in $O(2,\mathbb R)$ are conjugate (and hence will have isomorphic centralizers), we only need to pick one reflection; i.e., we don't need to write down a general formula for all reflections. We might as well just pick one that is easy to work with.

Comment: So I just took a random matrix A from reflections and another random matrix B from $O(2,R)$ $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) $ and checked the condition $AB=BA$ for any B from centraziler and got $a=d,b=c$ and then checked the $BB^t=E$ condition and got two solutions $a=1,b=1/2$ and $a=-1,b=-1/2$, am I right?

Comment: Something seems wrong. Exactly what $A$ did you pick?

Comment: The one I calculated before $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1-2x^2 & -2xy \\ -2xy & 1 -2y^2 \end{array} \right) $ 
So AB will be $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} (1-2x^2)a-2xyc & (1-2x^2)b-2xyd  \\ (1-2y^2)c-2xya & (1-2y^2)d -2xyb  \end{array} \right) $ and BA $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} (1-2x^2)a-2xyb & (1-2y^2)b-2xya  \\ (1-2x^2)c-2xyd & (1-2y^2)d -2xyc  \end{array} \right) $

Comment: This is not a specific $A$; this is a formula (involving $x$ and $y$) for a whole family of matrices. You only need to pick a specific reflection matrix for $A$.

Comment: So for example I can pick $y=-x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2})}$ and get $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} c & d \\ a & b  \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} b & a \\ d & c  \end{array} \right) $, what now?

Comment: You get $c=b$ and $d=a$. So you're looking at matrices of the form $\pmatrix{a&b\\b&a}$. You just need to determine which of these are in $O(2,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: For matrix A to be in $O(2,R)$ it is needed to $AA^t=E$ so I have all the matrces fo which is right $a^2+b^2=1, 2ab=0$ $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b \\ b & a \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b \\ b & a \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a^2+b^2 & 2ab \\ 2ab & a^2+b^2 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: Right, now what are the solutions to the system of equations $a^2+b^2=1, 2ab=0$?

Comment: I bet its $a=0,b=-1;a=0,b=1;a=1,b=0;a=-1,b=0$ so the order of centralizer is 4

Comment: Right, so then you just have to identify the structure of the group, i.e. which group of order 4 is it? (Up to isomorphism,there are only two groups of order 4: the cyclic group $Z_4$, or the Klein four group, $Z_2 \times Z_2$.)